# Send Events to Webview

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am trying to do send touch events to UIWebview remotely. I am trying to achieve something like LogMeIn app, where once remote is taken, the remote user can perform clicks/selection and scroll web-view on the user iPhone. I read through many links, but all are suggesting to use private api as you can't create touch events. If i use private api's then the app will get rejected  from appstore.

Answer (score 0):

use below URL to make call to functions from webview.
http://ramkulkarni.com/blog/framework-for-interacting-with-embedded-webview-in-ios-application/

In this delegate file

```
    - (id) processFunctionFromJS:(NSString *) name withArgs:(NSArray*) args error:(NSError **) error
```

method is there to get event of button click on webview.